# How to find specific the data as duplicate if one of the column is ±5 digit of previous data?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, this is the data in my data frame.

```
Column A Column B Column C
1        Apple    25
2        Banana   45
1        Apple    30
```

Currently, I'm using this line of code:

```
df['Repeat'] = df.duplicated(['Column A','Column C'])
```

If using this it will show the third one as no duplicate because the number not same.

Can I make is also consider as duplicate if the number is `± 5` digit if `Column A` is same?

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_dup(x):
    a = np.array([x['Column C']-5, x['Column C'], x['Column C']+5])
    b = df.loc[df['Column B']==x['Column B']]['Column C'].values
    return (np.equal(a[:, None],b).sum() > 1)

(
    df.assign(ind=df.apply(lambda x: is_dup(x), axis=1))
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['Column B', 'ind'])
    .drop('ind',1)
)


    Column A    Column B    Column C
0   1           Apple       25
1   2           Banana      45
```

Comment: I' not sure how to implement it into my code. Can you point me the direction? By the way I dont want remove it when it is repeated. Only mark a value "True" in Repeat column each of the row

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(x):
    return x['Column A'].duplicated() & (x['Column C'].diff().abs().le(5))

df = df.sort_values('Column B')
df[~df.groupby('Column B').apply(f).values]
```

**Result:**

```
  Column A  Column B    Column C
0   1          Apple    25
1   2         Banana    45
```

Comment: I think he meant within +/-5 range.

Comment: Updating my answer then.

Comment: You'd better clarify in comments first